# Lubuntu, broken fstab and non existent swap

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount, lubuntu, fstab

I did a fresh install of Lubuntu desktop (meant as a headless machine mostly), with formatting the disk via installer.

Apparently it didn't create a partition properly.. no GPT but msdos.

The machine wouldn't boot to the main drive unless i unplugged the 2nd SATA drive (for storage). Remained stuck on HP bios.

The system is currently running, i have SSH access, but unfortunately won't be physically accessing the machine for a while.

After hours of crawling the web for tutorials and discussions.. no success. I've only managed to trash the **fstab**, and obviously didnt make backup (not that it was any good..)

*here are a few cmd returns :*
**blkid**

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="1124c007-a2cd-4e2b-8942-06fca94f5f88" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="4ac38d5d-01"
```

**lsblk**

```
   NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 596,2G  0 disk 
└─sda1   8:1    0 596,2G  0 part /
```

**df**

```
    Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev             1959572       0   1959572   0% /dev
tmpfs             403696    1220    402476   1% /run
/dev/sda1      614267120 5072576 577921748   1% /
tmpfs            2018476       0   2018476   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120       4      5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs            2018476       0   2018476   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs             403692       4    403688   1% /run/user/1000
tmpfs             403692       0    403692   0% /run/user/117
```

**sudo parted -l**

```
Model: ATA WDC WD6400BEVT-8 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 640GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size   Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  640GB  640GB  primary  ext4
```

**swapon -s returns nothing**

How do i properly create a SWAP file with the current config (do i need one, how come the installer didn't make it?)

And most importantly what should the **fstab** look like please? So i can safely reboot the machine via SSH without fear of it not booting where it needs to and then the machine staying idle for weeks..

Thanks in advance !

(what will i need to run to be safe, regarding GRUB or else?)

ps: after install i had the following error (fwiw)

`cryptsetup: WARNING: The initramfs image may not contain cryptsetup binaries
nor crypto modules. If that's on purpose, you may want to uninstall the
'crypsetup-initramfs' package in order to disable the cryptsetup initramfs
integration and avoid this warning.`

.. removed cryptsetup and then ran `update-initramfs -u`

Comment: I'm confused by the part about booting and unplugging the 2nd drive. If you want partitions on that drive incorporated into the fstab, please provide info about them. No swap partition is the norm now, a swap file is used. (Assuming you are installing 18.04 or higher, you don't say). I also don't understand what you mean about gpt vs msdos, or what encryrption has to do with your situation. Details please.

Comment: Yes its 19.04 sorry forgot to mention. I do want to eventually use the 2nd drive for data only but currently more concerned about properly mounting the main one .  I did find swapiness (retunred 60), does that need to be specified in fstab? Concerning MSDOS, i'm just confused as to why the installed didn't go for GPT when the hardrive is capable. the encryption thing just as fwiw. What's for sure is that the OS won't drive unless i manually unplug the other SATA, which only has data and wasn't plugged during install.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I guess your current fstab is trashed so no point in adding it to the question? I will put together an fstab for you in a little while, when I get on a real pc.

Comment: yes it's beyond repair, pretty sure it won't boot again if i shut it as is. Concerning swap, if swapiness is on, shouldn't there be an alloted space and not **Swap:            0B          0B          0B**  ? Thanks for the help :)

Comment: does that loook viable to you for fstab ? `# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# /dev/sda1
UUID=1124c007-a2cd-4e2b-8942-06fca94f5f88       /               ext4            rw,relatime     0 1`

Comment: I am going to spin up a quick 19.04 virtual machine and see what the fstab looks like (all my installs are old and have swap partitions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just created a 19.04 Lubuntu virtual machine. Based on its fstab it looks like you need a single line like this:

`UUID=1124c007-a2cd-4e2b-8942-06fca94f5f88 /  ext4 defaults 0 1`

**Don't** include that device info `/dev/sda1`

Comment: worked great thank you, also had to go into BIOS and disable "fastboot" to prevent it from skipping stuff, many thanks !

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you.

Comment: If you want to mount a partition on the 2nd drive, use it's UUID and add a line like `UUID=[its-UUID] [mountpoint] ext4 defaults 0 2`  Before rebooting, try it with a `sudo mount -a`